# Why apache2 server does not working and when I check the status it shows the following ! :(

Tags: apache2

```
sudo systemctl status apache2

apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server    
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)    
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d   
           └─apache2-systemd.conf    
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-02-15 23:21:31 +06; 17min ago    
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)


Feb 15 23:21:31 jucse systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...    
Feb 15 23:21:31 jucse systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

How to activate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try using:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

if that doesn't work, try

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

although if `service` didn't work, I doubt `systemctl` will to any better.

If those error out, try

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

and it will give you any errors that occur.

Note: If you just want to do a config test(without trying to start apache), use:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

Based on your comment, it appears that your apache install is corrupt. In that case, try:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall apache2
```

to re-install apache. This should not affect any of your virtual hosts, but it's still a good idea to back up(something like `sudo cp -R /etc/apache2 /etc/apache2.old`)

Comment: When I try "sudo apachectl restart" is shows the following errors .


sudo apachectl restart  


/usr/sbin/apachectl: 154: /usr/sbin/apachectl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found


Action 'restart' failed.


The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: After reinstalling apache2 using 

sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2-bin

It works now ! 
Thanks a lot !